# Bridging from log4j2 to slf4j

Tags: maven, logging, slf4j, log4j2, dropwizard

I'm using Slf4j 1.7.x in conjunction with Logback in my applications (it is a Dropwizard-application). Now we have libraries that use the log4j2 (not log4j), and the logging goes to `/dev/null`. I can't find a `logj2-over-slf4j` or `log4j2-to-slf4j` library in any exising maven application, what is the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the [Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) to route your Log4j2 logs to your slf4j implementation. You are right that slf4j itself does not provide an adapter for log4j2.

Comment: Thanks, the specific dependency I was looking for was http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.logging.log4j|log4j-to-slf4j|2.2|jar